# How do I load webpage this way?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, ios-simulator

In a UIWebView, I provide a link to http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html.  In the simulator, TOC doesn't load.  A space for it appears then quickly hides.  However, on the iPhone, TOC loads and doesn't hide.  User has to click the hide TOC link.  What is the simulator doing that the iPhone isn't?  Is there a way to do that on the iPhone so TOC is hidden?

Comment: You may want to change the url to a tinyurl (or whatever), its causing the layout to break which will undoubtedly cause people to get frustrated and 'walk away'.

Comment: @meandmycode: it doesn't break the layout on FF3, what browser are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what the subtle difference is between the simulator and the device (something cookie related?), but I would suggest that your solution should be to wait until the page finishes loading and then inject the javascript to forcibly close the TOC, as with:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"showHideTOC('hide');"];
```

Comment: Thanks.  That works fine.  Do you why http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-stringByAppendingString_ instead goes to "rangeOfCharactersFromSet:" on iPhone & Simulator?

Comment: Disregard last comment.  It only happens in simulator.  Would have deleted comment and reposted but "x" is scrolling off the page because of my crazy link.